# What is the use of 2>&1 in shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

In shell scripting, `1 is file descriptor for standard output` and `2 is for standard error`. Now, since both of these point to console what is the use of
`2>&1`. Are not they already pointing to the same device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and do proper research in order to do useful questions

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is you are redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` so you get both error messages written to `FD2` as well as normal output on `FD1` written to `FD1`. (FD = File Descriptor). It generally allows you to capture the output of error messages you want to save in a log file, etc.. that would otherwise not be captured simply by redirecting `stdout` to the log.

By way of brief background, your shell has 3 well known file descriptors that cover basic reading and writing:

> **0** - stdin (your input buffer)
>
> **1** - stdout (your normal output descriptor)
>
> **2** - stderr (your normal error descriptor)

When you read or write, just about any programming language, including your shell, makes use of these common file descriptors to manage the input/output. In your shell, you have the ability to redirect or combine output from `stdout` and `stderr`. The general format is:

```
m > &n    ## where n & m are 1, 2
```

You can combine, for instance, both the `stdout` and `stderr` from any command to a file with:

```
./someprogram > myfile 2>&1
```

Which basically says, "take the output from `someprogram` on `stdout` redirect it to `myfile` while including `stderr` in `stdout`.

There are several good references, one being [**BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO: All about redirection**](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

**Note:** Be sure you also understand that redirection can happen on a temporary (per command basis) or can be set for the scope of the script using `exec`.